# Как посчитать количество файлов в папке С++

Tags: c++, файлы

Буквально в конце написания проекта столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу придумать как посчитать количество файлов в папке, чтобы создать вектор соответствующего размера. Гугл выдал результаты либо с помощью сторонних библиотек(что, конечно, допустимо, но нежелательно), либо для С, при помощи библиотеки dirent.h, которой либо нет в С++, либо нет конкретно у меня.

За сим вопрос - как посчитать количество файлов в папке, используя встроенные в кресты библиотеки?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в стандартной библиотеке это появилось только в С++17: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37494654/2076787 -- а до него только ОС-специфичное или кроссплатформенные общие API.

Comment: Или [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304891/how-to-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-standard).

Comment: Понял, принял. Странно, что сам не нашел, гран пардон. С утречка почекаю и апдейтну, если что. Спасибо!